Question on R square and adjusted R2
I  am reading a paper that used a Box-Behnken design (BBD) to study some parameters and their influence on the growth of bacteria. I am struggling to understand the statement made by the authors on the outcome (results) of the R square and R square adjusted values. The authors wrote:
'The given predicted R2 (0.83) and R2 adj. (0.72) values indicated that the model could describe 72-83% of the variability.'
Now I wondering: is this technically correct? Can you indeed state it as such, that the model can describe 72-83% of the variability based on the R2 and adj. R2 values?
I am not a statistics expert, but how I always saw it: the R2 value (and adj. R2 value) say something about how well the predictions of the fit the actual measured values.
To me this is different to what the authors state, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Welcome to Cross Validated! The BBD is an experimental design for collecting data that are then fed through a linear regression, correct?

I agree that this is a questionable way to do things; if the authors wanted a range of values that the R2 could have been, the natural thing to do would have been to compute a confidence interval for it!

When you look at my derivation here, I think it makes sense how, when the total variance can be broken into explained and unexplained variance, why the usual $R^2$ can be seen as the proportion of variance explained. Indeed, this is a common way to describe $R^2$ (such as here). Then my explanation here describes how adjusted $R^2$ tweaks the calculation with some different estimators of the unexplained and total variance.
However, considering the interval between adjusted and unadjusted $R^2$ to give a range of plausible proportions of variance explained does trouble me. I agree with the comments that it would make more sense to be explicit about calculating a confidence interval to obtain such a range (though, even if they did botch this part of the paper, I think this is a fairly minor error that should not discredit the rest of the findings).

I agree that I would not discredit their findings as they are valid and the work was good. The only think I am wondering about is how they 'explained' the result of the R2.  It' just the way they phrased it that I don't particularly like as I don't think it is 100% correct.
